# Increase column width for iotop

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, bash-scripting

Currently I'm using the iotop command to get snapshots of what my system is doing like so:

```
sudo iotop -C 10 20 > iotop.txt
```

However, in the output file, The text looks like this:

```
2017 Oct 14 16:13:45,  load: 1.41,  disk_r:  12504 KB,  disk_w:   1920 KB

  UID    PID   PPID CMD              DEVICE  MAJ MIN D            BYTES
  501    920      1 com.apple.toneli ??        1   4 R              512
  501    342      1 com.apple.geod   ??        1   4 W             4096
  501    917      1 FaceTime         ??        1   4 W             4096
    0     96      1 loginwindow      ??        1   4 R             8192
  202    175      1 coreaudiod       ??        1   4 W             8192
  501    922      1 com.apple.audio. ??        1   4 R             8192
  501    923      1 rtcreportingd    ??        1   4 W             8192
  501    280      1 sharedfilelistd  ??        1   4 W            12288
  501    385      1 NotificationCent ??        1   4 R            28672
    0    871      1 ocspd            ??        1   4 W            36864
    0    918      1 com.apple.cmio.r ??        1   4 R            40960
    0    919      1 AppleCameraAssis ??        1   4 R           143360
```

Some of app names in the `CMD` column are being cut off, which makes sense for outputting to the terminal, but when piping to a file, I need the full name. I checked the man pages for iotop but it doesn't look like there's an argument to increase the column width. I really need to track disk writes for all apps, so I either have to fix iotop output or use a different utility.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want?

**EDIT:** I tried to use `COLUMNS=1000 sudo iotop -C 10 20 > iotop2.txt` but that didn't work either...

Comment: Your setting of an environment variable won't work like that, because `sudo` creates a new environment. Try it in stages: `sudo -s`, then `export COLUMNS=1000` and finally `iotop -C 10 20 > iotop2.txt`. They can all be combined in a single command, but that's something to worry about after you find out if it makes any difference to the column width (I suspect it won't).

Comment: @AFH Unfortunately that didn't work either...

Comment: I think the best you'll be able to do is to extract each PID from the list and use `ps -ho cmd -p $PID` to append the full command to each line (for those programs which haven't terminated).